# python for absolute beginners third edition chapter 6 challenges 4 -tic tac toe-

Tags: python, function

i have been working on this project for a few day's now but i can't seem to find the solution... I need to modify my funtion computer_move.
I need to make it so when the player don't start in the center the npc need to set it's O in the oppiste corner to counter a win for the player.
I don't want the answer straight away i just need a litle hint on how i can solve this problem.

def computer_move(board, npc, human):

```
"""npc zet"""
board = board[:]
best_moves = (4, 8, 2, 6, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7)
print("Ik plaats mijn zet op nummer", end=" ")
# npc winnende zet
for move in legal_move(board):
    board[move] = npc
    if winner(board) == npc:
        print(move)
        return move
    # controleert move en ontdoet move
    board[move] = Empty
# npc blokkeert winnende zet speler
for move in legal_move(board):
    board[move] = human
    if winner(board) == human:
        print(move)
        return move
    board[move] = Empty
# Hoek zetten als center gespeeld is door speler
for move in legal_move(board):
    board[move] = human
    if human == best_moves[0]:
        print(best_moves[5])
        return best_moves[5]
    board[move] = Empty
    # beste zetten
for move in best_moves:
    if move in legal_move(board):
        print(move)
        return move
```

Comment: Is the full program too large to post?  It would be helpful to have a working example we could examine.  Also, the 'moves' list isn't documented in this snippet, and that might help if we could run this ourselves.

Comment: The program is to long to post , if there is any otherway to send you the full programm i gladly wil. I found this share link i uploaded text file . If you know a better share file let me me know please . ^--^                  https://easyupload.io/07e5f4                @asylumax

Comment: How many lines, BTW?  If you can strip this down to a minimum program, that can help.  It seems like your question is more algorithm related.   From your description, if a player doesn't start in the center, the NPC move is to go to the opposite corner. What if the player starts between corners?  The computer knows which move the games is on (n=1, 2, ... to a maximum of 9), so when n=1, you need to check to see if a) the first move is in the center and b) if the move is in the corner, choose the opposite corner.  It might help to show the labeling of the board.

Comment: Yes i just not know how to make it so the computers check first what the player moves is before making it own move.  Uuum i found pastebin maybe that's better?  https://pastebin.com/uehdrWXT                                          Would be very happy if you could check . ^-^ also code is 201 lines @asylumax

Comment: BTW, this looks like a homework problem; was this originally someplace else?  https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/s-problem-code-game-ties-end-figure-import-random-x-x-o-o-empty-tie-tie-numsquares-10-def--q43961483

Comment: I bought this book a few months ago , i just started studying it myself. dind't know it was on a site . :)                   But i could handle the other exercises . just struggling with this one . i will think about your adivce and rethink how i can find a solution